# Change WooCommerce "In Stock" text for custom product type (pre-order)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A little bit of background - I'm currently using the [Product Pre-Orders for WooCommerce plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-pre-orders-for-woo/) by VillaTheme.  Overall it works well for my purposes except for this one thing.

I’d like to make a custom “in stock” message for products that have the product type [“pre-order” box checked](https://ibb.co/h1Dh43H).

Currently I have implemented the below solution via php however it is cumbersome as it requires manually entering/updating the product ids.  I should also mention that these are variable products.

```
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) { 
    $product_ids = array(3831, 3832);
    // custom 
    if (in_array( $_product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('Available for Pre-Order', 'woocommerce'), $_product->get_stock_quantity());
    }

    // Out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Out of Stock', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

I would prefer a code solution that is able to automatically recognize when a product is designated as a pre-order item and update the “in stock” text accordingly.

Any updates you can make to my code to function as described are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```php
/**
 * Change availability text.
 *
 * @param array      $availability  Availability data array.
 * @param WC_Product $_product      WC Product object.
 *
 * @return array.
 */
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    $is_preorder = 'no';

    if ( $_product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $is_preorder = get_post_meta( $_product->get_id(), '_wpro_variable_is_preorder', true );
    } elseif ( $_product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $_variations     = $_product->get_available_variations();
        $_variations_ids = ! empty( $_variations ) ? wp_list_pluck( $_variations, 'variation_id' ) : array();
        if ( ! empty( $_variations_ids ) ) {
            $is_preorders = array_map(
                function( $id ) {
                    return wc_string_to_bool( get_post_meta( $id, '_wpro_variable_is_preorder', true ) );
                },
                $_variations_ids
            );
            $is_preorder  = in_array( true, $is_preorders, true ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        }
    } else {
        $is_preorder = get_post_meta( $_product->get_id(), '_simple_preorder', true );
    }

    if ( wc_string_to_bool( $is_preorder ) ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __( 'Available for Pre-Order', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I can confirm tested and working.  Now there is a new issue presented.  Although the [product page](https://ibb.co/XbD9nZh) displays the text correctly, it does not appear to carry over to the [shop page](https://ibb.co/KzDCH0x).  Do you have any suggestions on how we may be able to solve this?

Comment: By default, WooCommerce doesn't show stock status on the Archive page, so it's your theme that added that status. You need to find out if they added it using the different function or using the default WooCommerce function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I added the following code to my theme to activate that function:

```function puri_shop_loop_show_stock() {
   global $product;
   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'puri_shop_loop_show_stock', 10 );```

Comment: Ok, so you have variable products in the Archive page and when you use the `wc_get_stock_html( $product )` code, you actually using the parent product object, not the variation product object, so you get `_simple_preorder` false and code doesn't change the text there.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for the explanation.  Do you have any suggestions on how I should modify the code to apply to the variation product object rather than the parent product object (or both)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think that should do the job properly.

Comment: Good to know, If you encounter any errors, Please me know so that I could improve my answer. Thanks